# How to change the number of columns my default Foundation 5 grid uses?

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I'd like to change the default number of columns my Foundation 5 grid uses from 12 to 24 for example. I have seen the F5 grid doc page over here

https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/grid.html

but there are really no detailed instructions. What I see is this:

> **Customize with Sass** 
>   Customizing the grid is easy with the Sass
>   variables provided in the `_settings.scss` file.
>
> *SCSS*
>
> $row-width: rem-calc(1000); 
>   $column-gutter: rem-calc(30);
>   $total-columns: 12 ;

When I uncomment `$total-columns: 12 ;` and change it to `$total-columns: 24 ;` absolutely nothing happens. Once again, I'm not seeing really detailed instructions here so I've no idea if I'm doing this right. So what is the proper way to change the number of columns my default Foundation 5 grid uses?

Comment: I assume you're recompiling your Sass *after* making the change, right?

Comment: yes of course via grunt libsass

Comment: Are you sure that your _settings.scss partial is being included?

Comment: I think it is not being included because if it was, I would see the changes show up but I'm not. I think I've something funky going on with my Foundation components path in my Gruntfile.js. I realize I should probably post a new question regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

If your running the watch task, either with compass or grunt, you will see the compile run in the command line when you save.

If you already built a 12 columns grid, then changed to 24, you would see the first set of columns floated left the rest to the right leaving a big gap in the middle.

```
    // $row-width: rem-calc(1000);
    $total-columns: 24;
    // $column-gutter: rem-calc(30);
```

Comment: right but like I said, when I change the value and it recompiles the scss, nothing changes in the browser. it's like the `_settings.scss` file is not even being seen. I should open a new issue regarding this.